# What does Erik gain by lying to the Persian about the chandelier?

Tags: french-language, gaston-leroux, the-phantom-of-the-opera

When the Persion meets Erik on the underground lake, and confronts him about the chandelier, Erik denies any involvement:

> "Well, the chandelier... the chandelier, Erik?..."
> "What about the chandelier?"
> "You know what I mean."
> "Oh," he sniggered, "I don't mind telling you about the chandelier!... *It wasn't I!*... The chandelier was very old and worn."
> When Erik laughed, he was more terrible than ever. He jumped into the boat, chuckling so horribly that I could not help trembling.
> "Very old and worn, my dear daroga! Very old and worn, the chandelier!... It fell of itself!... It came down with a smash!... And now, daroga, take my advice and go and dry yourself, or you'll catch a cold in the head!... And never get in my boat again.... And, whatever you do, don't try to enter my house: I'm not always there.... daroga! And I should be sorry to have to dedicate my Requiem Mass to you!"
> <sub>*The Phantom of the Opera*, chapter XXI: "Interesting and Instructive Vicissitudes of a Persian in the Cellers of the Opera" ([translation by](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/22415/58) Alexander Teixeira de Mattos, 1911)</sub>

However, later on, when Raoul and the Persian are trapped in the torture chamber, and Christine is with Erik, Erik admits to being involved pretty heavily:

> Meantime, the other had already begun to play the ventriloquist. He said:
> "Here, I raise my mask a little... Oh, only a little!... You see my lips, such lips as I have? They're not moving! [...]  What does it say? '*I am the little bag of life and death!*'... And now, crack! It is in Carlotta's throat, in Carlotta's golden throat, in Carlotta's crystal throat, as I live! What does it say? It says, 'It's I, Mr. Toad, it's I singing! *I feel without alarm—co-ack—with its melody enwind me—co-ack!'... And now, crack! It is on a chair in the ghost's box and it says, '*Madame Carlotta is singing to-night to bring the chandelier down!*'... And now, crack! Aha! Where is Erik's voice now? Listen, Christine, darling! Listen!["]
> <sub>*The Phantom of the Opera*, chapter XXIII: "The Tortures Begin"</sub>

The Persian is well aware of Erik's past history - indeed, being pretty much the *only* person to know Erik's history - and is aware that he's killed in the past and is capable of killing in the present. Why, then, would Erik lie to the daroga? The Persian isn't stupid; what does Erik stand to gain by lying to the Persian after almost killing him?